# Wrong Output when adding list to dict

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add lists `l` as values for different dict `d` keys. For the array `a`, having `[6,12,18,24,30]` I am trying to get the dict `d` to contain the following key-value pairs:

```
d[6] = [0, 0, 0.....0]
d[12] = [6, 0, 0, ..0]
d[18] = [6, 12, 0, ...0]
d[24] = [6, 12, 18, 0, ..0]
```

Where there are 59 elements in each of the lists above.

I use the code below to do this, but my output for the key `24` is:

```
{24: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 18, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

I am trying to understand where I am going wrong.

```
d = {}
l = []
a =numpy.array([6,12,18,24,30])
for x, value in numpy.ndenumerate(a): 
    months_to_maturity = value
    for i in range(6, 354, 6):
        if i <= months_to_maturity:
            l.append(months_to_maturity - i)
        else:
            l.append(0)

    d[months_to_maturity] = l
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is your expected output compared to actual output?

Comment: @Claris I've written in the question what kind of output I get and what I want. I have said I am getting the wrong output and haven't mentioned getting an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're always appending to the same list. Thus all the dictionary values end up pointing to the same list. You want to append to a different list each time:

```
d = {}
a = numpy.array([6, 12, 18, 24, 30])
for months_to_maturity in a:
    l = []
    for i in range(6, 354, 6):
        if i <= months_to_maturity:
            l.append(months_to_maturity - i)
        else:
            l.append(0)

    d[months_to_maturity] = l
```